# Determine if logged in with username and password or with Facebook in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How do I check if I'm logged in with a username/password or with Facebook authentication?

I want to have a condition that says something like

```
if (loggedInWithUserNamePassword()) {
   // show change password screen
} else { // logged in with Facebook
  // don't show change password screen
}
```

I'm looking through "User." and "Request." for options to use but nothing seems like it shows a clear sign that I'm logged in with Facebook or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuing you already have the API of Facebook connected and up and running. 
Naming the FaceBook api connection to Variable FB. This is how you check.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

So Yes, this is a JS call, currently FB does not support getLoginStatus for C# API implementation, however you can always return an Async Result to your Server Call with the JS response and work your way in there.

Comment: on the page where I need the check I'm not calling any Facebook API's, so this wouldn't apply to my scenario

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, although it's not what I'm looking for...

In ApplicationUser I created a field called

```
public bool IsSocialAccount {get; set};
```

and when I create the account, if its from a username/password the value is false, else true.

Then I can chcek this in my controlller.

I was looking for a more built in approach to checking but this will do

Comment: What about storing a cookie in the client whenever the user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationUser.PasswordHash will be null if the account has only been used with a social login. So if you are assuming that all accounts have only a single login mechanism (either username/password or a social login), then this should be able to tell between the two.

If you allow multiple login mechanisms with the same account (which is supported by ASP.NET Identity), you'll need a different approach.

Comment: when you say "allow multiple login mechanisms" what do you mean? Right now I have username/password, Facebook and I have Google set up but I have disabled it. So Google would be the only other method to login.

Comment: It is possible to set things up so a person can log into the same User with either username/password or Facebook, for instance. So when they go to log in for a particular session, they could use either their username/password or Facebook, and either way be logged in with the same ASP.NET Identity. The AddLoginAsync is the ASP.NET Identity API that lets you add additional ways to log in.

Comment: I don't see any static method for PaswordHash in ApplicationUser?

Comment: It isn't a static method. It will be a column stored in the AspNetUsers table, and exposed as a field on the appropriate C# class in your application. Depending on exactly how your tables are set up, the column could be called something else, but it should be recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/) NuGet package to authenticate users from Facebook you could check users claims to determine how they authenticated. To do so simply write a extension method to check if the user signed in by Facebook or not:

```
public static bool IsSignedInWithFacebook(this IIdentity identity)
{
    // since the Facebook authentication handler add following claim
    // we could check to see if user has this claim or not
    var claimIdent = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    return claimIdent != null
        && claimIdent.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:name");
}
```

Now use this extension method wherever you want like this:

```
if(User.Identity.IsSignedInWithFacebook())
{
    // do what you want
}
```